# How do I use "catchall" in my postfix alias?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, regex, aliases

I have this in my main.cnf:

```
alias_maps= regexp:/etc/aliases
```

Inside that file, I have:

```
/^reply*$/: jjj
```

Now, when I send it to reply-124233@mydomain.com, postfix bounces it because

```
Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table;
```

How can I configure my aliases so that people can send reply*@mydomain.com and forward it to jjj@mydomain.com?

Comment: Is mydomain.com your primary domain, or is it a virtual domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that's not a typo and `/^reply*$/: jjj` really is the entry in your table, then your regular expression is incorrect for what you are trying to do and you are not using the proper syntax for [`regexp_table(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html)

You'd want `/^reply.*$/ jjj`.

I think you might also be better served by adding and additional table rather than overriding the standard one.

`alias_maps = hash:/etc/mail/aliases, regexp:/etc/postfix/reply-regexp-alias`

Also, keep in mind that [`alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps) are used for [`local(8)`](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) and not [`virtual(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) delivery, meaning that the system this is occurring on must think of itself as the final destination for all @mydomain.com addresses, though something thing can be done with [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps).

Comment: What's the difference between local and virtual? For my purpose, actually I am piping it to a script. Whenever someone sends an email to reply-12345@mydomain.com, my postfix will catch it via the regexp and pipe it to a python script.  Then, my python script will insert a record into the database.

Comment: @Alex You can read the links documentation for a more full understanding, but if you are piping to a script you definitely want local, as virtual does not allow for that kind of behavior.